Can the output of a well-defined function with no input be empty?
I was working on the following problem:

Suppose the triplet $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$ is a measure space. Let $f:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function. Show that $f^{-1}(\mathcal{B})$ := {$f^{−1}(B) : B \in \mathcal{B}$} is a sigma algebra. (here $\mathcal{B}$ denotes the Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$).

By definition of $\sigma$-algebra, the set $\Omega$ should lie in the $\sigma$-algebra, and so does its complement i.e. $\emptyset$. So, I tried to come up with arguments to show that $\emptyset$ lies in $f^{-1}(\mathcal{B}$), which made me stumble on the question, what will be the output of $f(\emptyset)$?
Further, can we ask a general question like for any arbitrary well-defined function, say for example, $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined as $f(x) = 2x + 1$, what will be the output for the function when we do not give any input to it i.e. what is the value of $f(${}$)$? Can it be {} i.e. the empty set or in other sense nothing?

Yes, the preimage of the empty set is the empty set.

There seems to be an underlying confusion here, just because we're talking about preimages $f^{-1}(B)$, that the function $f$ somehow takes sets as inputs and returns values for them. That's not the case: the inputs to the function $f$ are simply elements of $\Omega$ as always. So the notation $f(\emptyset)$ is meaningless here.
Fortunately that's not needed to show that $\emptyset$ does lie in $f^{-1}(\mathcal B)$. We need to show that there exists $B\in\mathcal B$ such that $f^{-1}(B)=\emptyset$. One can check that $B=\emptyset$ satisfies this: the set $f^{-1}(\emptyset) = \{ x\in\Omega\colon f(x)\in\emptyset\} = \emptyset$ because $f(x)\in\emptyset$ is impossible.

Could you provide an answer to the question asked in the last paragraph?

The notation $f({})$ doesn't make sense for the value of a function, nor does not giving a function an input. That's like saying only “The square root of.” It doesn't have any meaning.

Remember that $\emptyset \subset \mathbb R$, not $\emptyset \in \mathbb R$, and that even though we use the same notation for applying a funtion to an element or a subset, they are actually two different things.
